# Find the values of a and b that make the equation system have infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I'm given the following system of equations and I need to find the values for a and b so that the system has infinite solutions.
\begin{cases}
&3y &- &2z &= 5 \\
&-2x &+ &az &= -7 \\
&3x &- &2y &= b
\end{cases}

I know that in order for the system to have infinite solutions the rank of the matrix of the coefficents should be the same as the rank of the augmented matrix and lower than the number of equations, but I'm not sure how to find the values of a and b that satisfy such a condition.

Comment: Start with the coefficient matrix. If the rank is $3$ there is exactly one solution, so what does that tell you about $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The augmented matrix $[A\mid b~]$ is$$\begin{vmatrix}0&3&-2&|&5\\-2&0&a&|&-7\\3&-2&0&|&b\end{vmatrix}$$After reducing $A$ to row-echelon form:$$\begin{vmatrix}3&-2&0&|&b\\0&3&-2&|&5\\0&0&a-8/9&|&2b/3-43/9\end{vmatrix}$$Now, $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}([A\mid b~])<3\implies a=8/9,b=43/6$.

Comment: What row operations were applied in order to reduce the matrix to the row-echelon form?

Comment: @Agus In order: $R_1\leftrightarrow R_3,R_2\leftrightarrow R_3,R_3\to R_3+2R_1/3+4R_2/9$

Answer (score 1):

For infinite solution there are two conditions

1. $N(A)\neq\{0\}$
2. $b\in Col(A)$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying 2. with 3 and 3. equation with 2 and add them we get $$3az-4y = -21+2b$$ Multiplying this one with 3 and 1. one with 4 we get: $$-8z+9az=20-63+6b$$

and thus $$ z(9a-8)= 6b-43$$ So if

- $ a = {8\over 9}$ and $b={43\over 6}$ we have infinite solutions.
- $ a = {8\over 9}$ and $b\ne {43\over 6}$ we have no solution.
- $ a \ne {8\over 9}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have one solution.